# How do you set an alias in zsh on Mac OS

Tags: macos, zsh

I've set a zsh alias like this:

```
alias sed="/usr/local/Cellar/gnu-sed/4.8/bin/gsed"
```

I can confirm it is working by running:

```
type sed
sed is an alias for /usr/local/Cellar/gnu-sed/4.8/bin/gsed
```

However, if I put exactly the same code, alias setting and type sed then in a script under the file name test and run it get the default sed:

```
zsh test
sed is /usr/bin/sed
```

I've also tried it with extending PATH and still get the same thing which puzzles me...

Comment: If you enter a shell with a different setup, you won't see your aliases...

Comment: Also, note that in POSIX-compliant shells (which zsh isn't, but takes many cues from), aliases are turned off altogether during script execution, even if they _are_ set in that shell. To speak beyond that, though, I'd need to see your _exact_ script and how you invoke it to speak definitively. It's very different if you expect executing the script as a subprocess to change the configuration of your main shell, vs if you expect the configuration of your main shell to be reflected in the child process that runs the script, vs if you expect the child process that runs the script to read dotfiles.

Comment: (All of those expectations are wrong, but they're wrong in different ways; so if we don't know your _exact_ test procedure we can't describe exactly why your test resulted in something other than what you expected).

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that worked for me was to create a function. After that sed was overriden with gsed when I called the help argument

```
#!/bin/bash
sed () {
    /usr/local/Cellar/gnu-sed/4.8/bin/gsed "$@"
}
sed --help
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the command word `sed` as `gsed` in all your future scripts (which if you really want to do, you can do this), Homebrew has info on how to achieve this, at the end of the installation for `brew install gsed`:

```
GNU "sed" has been installed as "gsed".
If you need to use it as "sed", you can add a "gnubin" directory
to your PATH from your bashrc like:

    PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/gnu-sed/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
```

Though you are asking about `zsh` so I'm assuming you've upgraded to at least macOS Catalina and are now trying to use `zsh` instead of `bash`, so that means I would suggest putting the suggested line from Homebrew into `~/.zshrc` instead of `~/.bashrc`.

Some things have changed, the default Homebrew installation directory is now, well you can use the command `brew --prefix` to get your directory, it's now currently `/opt/homebrew` instead of the old `/usr/local/Cellar`.

Now your `sed` should run as `gsed` in all your scripts.

##### Additional notes

Reasons why your code involving aliases isn't working as expected and some additional notes to take away (speaking to `zsh` and `bash`):

1. Aliases in a script file disappear after the script has been run (unless the script is called by another script, then the calling script has the new alias definition).
2. Aliases executed in startup files like "~/.zshrc" etc. aren't used within script files.

Comment: I've already tried this and same result :) Look at the last sentence of the problem description. If you are running Mac, give it a try please before posting.

Comment: I've tried it on my Mac and it works. Are you running an older version of macOS? Did you install `gsed` with Homebrew? Do you have the PATH statement at the very end of your config file? Which default shell are you running, `bash` or `zsh`? The config file you want to write to will depend on your default shell. If you do `open /opt/homebrew/opt/gnu-sed/libexec/gnubin`, does the directory open for you in Finder? Does `type -a sed` show on the first line `/opt/homebrew/opt/gnu-sed/libexec/gnubin/sed`? @user51195

Comment: Do you have `#!/bin/zsh` at the top if you're using `~/.zshrc`, or `#!/bin/bash` at the top if you're using `~/.bashrc`? What do you get when you type `echo "$SHELL"`? Do you have `eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"` in your `~/.zprofile` (if you're using `zsh`)? If you do `bash` and type `sed --version` does it work to give you the version text for GNU sed?

Comment: I'm still here to help if you still need help. Could it be possible that your PATH is changing because you're switching between shells? And the shell config that you switch to adds onto the config of the first shell? @user51195

Comment: I get /bin/zsh when I run echo "$SHELL". I have the latest MacOS. I've installed gsed with Homebrew. I don't have ~/.bashrc nor ~/.zprofile but only ~/.zshrc. Nothing interesting in ~/.zshrc except maybe that I am using oh-my-zsh :)
Anyway, it seemed very unexpected behaviour to me but since it's not reproducible on other macs, it's not worth digging further...

Comment: When you `echo "$PATH` in your script file, do you get `/opt/homebrew/opt/gnu-sed/libexec/gnubin` in front? Ah, well I've heard ohmyzsh does a lot of behind-the-scenes configuration, that could be the cause, not sure since I don't use ohmyzsh.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass 3 step for set alias on mac,
suppose we need to set this command as alias

```
alias runner='dart run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs'
```

Open your terminal and run the command:

1. touch .zshr
2. open ~/.zshrc

Paste your alias on the editor like below - and save it.

[image: set alias]